# Convention for selection of summary slices in fMRI

Tags: fmri, visualization, publication

Looking at papers, I often see an fMRI volume summarised by taking a single axial, sagittal and coronal slice (typically in MNI152 space). For an example see Figure 1 in de Bie et al, 2011 [1]. 
The text of a number of papers I have browsed doesn't explain how the slices are selected.

My question is what methods are conventional for selecting the x,y,z slice co-ordinates in such figures?

[1] https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alle_meije_Wink/publication/51077270_Resting-state_networks_in_awake_five-_to_eight-year_old_children/links/0fcfd50a5fafa7a0bb000000.pdf

Comment: which coordinates best highlight the thing the paper is trying to show

Comment: Ooh, burn :) Understand your point, but I'm a stats person, so a) I want a principled method (realise I asked for conventional though), and b) doing this manually each time would be a bad outcome compared to writing software.

Comment: hmm.  you could automatically select the slices with highest average activation?